# Schedule a local notification 2 days before a date (selected by the user)

Tags: ionic3, uilocalnotification

I have an application coded with ionic 3 which must record the date of an event, then remind the user (via local notifications) 2 days before the event and the day before the event.
when i run the code below i don't get any error, but i also don't see my notification when i try to list all registered notifications with this.localNotifications.getAll ();

I get the date using this: `<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY à HH:mm" pickerFormat="D MMMM YYYY HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate" name="tokoss"></ion-datetime>`

then I create the notification as well

```
myDate : Date ;
setNotification(){
    var date = new Date(this.myDate);
    date.setDate(date.getDay()-2); //back for 2 days
    console.log(date);
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      text: 'Single Local Notification 2 days',
      trigger: { at: new Date(date) },
      data: { secret: 'secret' }
    });
  }
```

how to fix this problem please

Comment: The only possible cause of error is the value being set against trigger. Could you do a `console.log( new Date(date) )` and post the output in the question ?

Comment: Thank you @ – Delwyn Pinto  for your answer. in another forum i was advised to use date-fns to manipulate dates, i did and it seems to work, except i have the following issues when i run my code:
- the first and second notifications do not run at the scheduled time (6 a.m. for the first and 8 a.m. for the second), but run at the same time with the 3rd (scheduled for 3 p.m.)
- when its change from "twoDayAgo" to oneDayAgo, all oneDayAgo notificatons are executed at the same time as the first (scheduled at 6h)
please what's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ – Delwyn Pinto  for your answer. in another forum i was advised to use date-fns to manipulate dates, i did and it seems to work, except i have the following issues when i run my code:

- the first and second notifications do not run at the scheduled time (6 a.m. for the first and 8 a.m. for the second), but run at the same time with the 3rd (scheduled for 3 p.m.)
- when its change from "twoDayAgo" to oneDayAgo, all oneDayAgo notificatons are executed at the same time as the first (scheduled at 6h)
  please what's the problem with my code?

my code:

```
 let date = new Date(this.myDate);
let twoDaysAgo = addDays(date, -2);
let oneDaysAgo = addDays(date, -1);

// 2 days ago first notification
twoDaysAgo.setHours(6,0,0);
this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      text: 'local notification 2 days ago 6h',
      trigger: { at: twoDaysAgo },
      data: { secret: 'secret' }
    });

    // 2 days ago 2nd notification
    twoDaysAgo.setHours(8,0,0);
this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 2,
      text: 'local notification 2 days ago 8h',
      trigger: { at: twoDaysAgo },
      data: { secret: 'secret' }
    });

    // 2 days ago 3rd notification
    twoDaysAgo.setHours(15,0,0);
this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 3,
      text: 'local notification 2 days ago 15h',
      trigger: { at: twoDaysAgo },
      data: { secret: 'secret' }
    });
    // 1 days ago 1st notification
  oneDaysAgo.setHours(6,0,0);
  this.localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 4,
    text: 'Local notification one day ago 6h',
    trigger: { at: oneDaysAgo },
    data: { secret: 'secret' }
  });

  // 1 days ago 2nd notification
  oneDaysAgo.setHours(8,0,0);
  this.localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 5,
    text: 'Local notification one day ago 8h',
    trigger: { at: oneDaysAgo },
    data: { secret: 'secret' }
  });
  // 1 days ago 3rd notification
  oneDaysAgo.setHours(15,0,0);
  this.localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 6,
    text: 'Local notification one day ago 15h',
    trigger: { at: oneDaysAgo },
    data: { secret: 'secret' }
  });
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on the question, the problem is to do with the value against trigger. You need to console log the values against trigger at every stage. You need to know the input to understand why the output isn't as expected right ?